# Lane detection in a most-shadowed image with some light

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Currently I'm working on finding lane lines in an image with OpenCV and C++.

However, I encountered a big problem utilizing a good threshold on the following picture.

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEqZx.jpg)

I have tried using some thresholding methods below, but none of them worked.

> 1. sobel x filter with min threshold 10 and max threshold 60
> 2. sobel y filter with min threshold 10 and max threshold 60
> 3. R channel in BGR color space with min threshold 30 and max threshold 60
> 4. S channel in HLS color space and U channel in YUV color space. No matter what threshold I took in these 2 color spaces, it looks like disaster.

Take [BGR-R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK1Bx.jpg) as example, the lane lines are clear but the bright part is also obvious.

I have tried `Histogram equalization` to balance white and black part in image before thresholding, but it enhanced the contrast, which makes the result even worse.

I don't know whether I can categorize this problem as shadow-removal, because most part in the image is covered by shadow.

I wish someone can teach me what pre-process steps I could take or any possible methods which can find the line.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try [LineSegmentDetector](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#linesegmentdetector-detect).

Comment: Why not create a mask of the image where you know the lane lines should roughly be within? For starters the lane lines won't be in the top half of your image, will converge in from the sides, and won't exist in a triangle centered at the bottom.

Comment: @dhanushka I tried but the results looks not positive, it will find out too many lines except lanes.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds because in the end I want to apply my program to a video. I think the bottom part will be too difficult to mask because the location of lanes differ.

Comment: I implemented a lane detection algorithm once that used a mask. I made a generic mask that I thought was reasonable to assume that you start in, and then once I detected the lane lines, I updated the mask every frame to be around the lane lines from the previous frame. Basically if my lane lines looked like /  \ then my mask looked like / /\ \.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I got it. How about curved lane lines. Will your mask still fit for it? And the other concern is that maybe we will get a bad result at the beginning of the video. Then I worried the mask will never fit. Thanks for your patience and response!

Comment: Instead of a mask, you can simply ignore detected lines that aren't around the lines from the previous frame. So same idea as a mask but not explicitly masked. Anyways these are just some small suggestions, they do not answer the actual question of preprocessing.